# All files in directories tomcat_*/temp should be deleted on each application restart

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tomcat, find

We do have an operation script to stop, restart and start tomcat services. I am asked to make changes in the operation script so when starting tomcat with operation_script.sh, All files in directories tomcat_*/temp should be deleted on each application start.

Script is long so I will do snippet.

```
## service tomcat
if [[ ${service} == "tomcat" ]]; then

  case ${operation} in 
    stop) # stop tomcat java processes
    
      $DIR/command_bsiadmin.sh "
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_ui}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_be}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_se}.service; " "$1"
      tomcat_status
      ;;
    
    start) # start tomcat java processes  

      $DIR/command_bsiadmin.sh "
      find /opt/tsi/app/tomcat_*/temp/* -exec rm -rf {} + \; 2>/dev/null; # Here I apply my solution 
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_se}.service;  
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_be}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_ui}.service;
```

After the tomcats started, None of temp files were deleted. Tested several times but I have no idea where I am doing wrong.  Shouldn't `find -exec rm` command delete all files in directories tomcat_*/temp??? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about using another semicolon after `+`. Try to remove the semicolon and see if it helps.

Also you really don't need to use `find` since you're using recursive mode already.  `rm -fr -- /opt/tsi/app/tomcat_*/temp/*` should suffice.  It's also commendable to enable `nullglob`.  Don't add `2>/dev/null` so you see errors.

Comment: `rm -fr -- /opt/tsi/app/tomcat_*/temp/* 2>/dev/null` should work like this?

Comment: If you still want to add `2>/dev/null` sure.